# How can I force Visual Studio to follow a custom CSS template when I edit my css files?

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio, formatting

I want VS to place a specific amount of tabs to help me write my css in such format:

```
#divAddParts
{
    width                   :400px;
    padding                 :5px;

    }
```

Is it possible to create a specific document template for css, for JavaScript etc so that I do not have to enter TAB to arrange my document?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to the **Tools->Options** Menu, then expand "**Text Editor**"  and pick which language you want to format. Here you can set Tabs, and formatting properties for each language!